# Quartz + Workmanager with Spring on a clustered environment

Tags: spring, weblogic, quartz-scheduler, workmanagers

We want to execute jobs on a clustered WebLogic environment. Quartz (running on clustered mode) is used to persist the jobs and WorkManager is used to create the threads to run the jobs.

However, the first Quartz instance immediately locks all the jobs and this prevents another node/server to do parallel execution.

This locking of all jobs is thanks to [LocalTaskExecutorThreadPool](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/scheduling/quartz/LocalTaskExecutorThreadPool.html)

```
public int blockForAvailableThreads() {

     // The present implementation always returns 1, making Quartz (1.6)
     // always schedule any tasks that it feels like scheduling.
     // This could be made smarter for specific TaskExecutors,
     // for example calling <code>getMaximumPoolSize() - getActiveCount()</code>
     // on a <code>java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor</code>.
     return 1;
}
```

Other than providing another implementation of this class, is there a better way to do parallel execution of jobs on a clustered environment using a Weblogic WorkManager?

Answer (score 0):

Have you explored the option of defining the timer as a [clustered singleton service](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs92/ConsoleHelp/taskhelp/clusters/ConfigureSingletonService.html) from the WebLogic side? The steps may be different for the version you're using.